# Rbind two vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, rbind

I have a data.frame with several columns I'd like to join into one column in a new data.frame.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = 4:6, col3 = 7:9)
```

how would I create a new data.frame with a single column that's 1:9?

Comment: The title doesn’t quite match the description …

Comment: `library(reshape2); melt(df1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `data.frame`s are essentially lists of columns, `unlist(df1)` will give you one large vector of all the values. Now you can simply construct a new `data.frame` from it:

```
data.frame(col = unlist(df1))
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you want an indicator too:

```
stack(df1)
#   values  ind
# 1      1 col1
# 2      2 col1
# 3      3 col1
# 4      4 col2
# 5      5 col2
# 6      6 col2
# 7      7 col3
# 8      8 col3
# 9      9 col3
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to provide a complete set of ways to do that, here is the `tidyr` way.

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df1)
   key value
1 col1     1
2 col1     2
3 col1     3
4 col2     4
5 col2     5
6 col2     6
7 col3     7
8 col3     8
9 col3     9
```

Answer (score 6):

One more using `c` function:

```
data.frame(col11 = c(df1,recursive=TRUE))
      col11
col11   1
col12   2
col13   3
col21   4
col22   5
col23   6
col31   7
col32   8
col33   9
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
as.data.frame(as.vector(as.matrix(df1)))
#  as.vector(as.matrix(df1))
#1                         1
#2                         2
#3                         3
#4                         4
#5                         5
#6                         6
#7                         7
#8                         8
#9                         9
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, just for using `Reduce`...

```
data.frame(Reduce(c, df1))
```